# Update rows and set column value to some string + id

Tags: mysql

I have a table two columns, `id` and `description`. `id` is primary key and auto increment, `description` is a varchar.

Is there any way to make an update statement that populates the `descrption` column with something like `"this row has id: @id"`. Where `@id` is the current id. Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    description = CONCAT('this row has id: @', id);
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure. Use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE theTable
SET description = CONCAT('this row has id: ', CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10)))
```

In fact, in MySQL, from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

> A numeric argument is converted to its equivalent binary string form

And in this case, a binary string will do just fine, and you can just do:

```
UPDATE theTable
SET description = CONCAT('this row has id: ', id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
UPDATE myTable SET
   description = concat('this row has id: @', id)
```